# Google BigQuery-Joined Resultset from Multiple Table

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello I am Importing Google Analytics CostData to Google BigQuery each day, table is created like Costdata_yyyymmdd for each day. I need  a joined result in a Select query for all the dates table.

TableName

Costdata_20180401

Costdata_20180402

Costdata_20180403

Costdata_20180404

Costdata_20180405
.....
Costdata_yyyymmdd

Required Result:

```
select * from Costdata_20180401
union all 
select * from Costdata_20180402 
union all Costdata_yyyymmdd
```

What would be the best approach in Google BigQuery to achieve this ?

Comment: Your question is a bit too general - examples and expected outcome would be great. In case you're asking how joins work: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types

Comment: Hi Martin I have added examples and expected outcome. I need to union dynamic generated table..may be i need a view where i can write my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table wildcards for this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference

```
SELECT * 
FROM  ´Costdata_*´ 
WHERE _table_suffix 
  BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180413'
```